# Need to unhide a row if 5 cells values change to a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a questionnaire where certain questions hide or show depending on the responses.

I've managed this for individual cell changes.

The problem I am having is that if 5 questions are responded to with value "No" then a certain row un-hides.

So if cells `K20`,`K22`,`K24`, `K30` and `K32` all change to `"No"` then unhide `row 34`

I've tried creating a formula cell that reads all the values and outputs "Yes" if the 5 questions are "No" but I think the cell value is not changing as its a formula not a value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to VBA and against the clock.

Kind regards, :)

Here's the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address(False, False) = "S32" And Target.Value = "Yes" Then
      Call PQShowQ7
       Else
End If

End Sub
```

Which activates this Module

```
Sub PQShowQ7()

With Sheets("Initial Scoping - WIP")

    Sheets("Initial Scoping - WIP").Unprotect ("xxx")

        .Range("A34", "A35").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Sheets("Initial Scoping - WIP").Protect ("xxx")

        .Range("J34").Value = "Please Select:"

    End With

    Sheets("Initial Scoping - WIP").Protect ("xxx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this code?

Comment: Just updated it :)

Comment: Think you've diagnosed your own problem. The change event is not triggered by a formula change. You could use the Calculate event or use Mikku's approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of Doing a Formula and checking that, You can change it to**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Range("K20") = "No" And Range("K22") = "No" And Range("K24") = "No" And Range("K30") = "No" And Range("K32") = "No" Then

      Call PQShowQ7

End If

End Sub
```